# MYSQL - compare rows from two different tables and return the difference between the two rows

Tags: mysql, compare

I have two tables in a database that have identical columns.  One table tracks the current state of the object with all its metadata and security and the other table tracks previous versions of the object with the previous versions of metadata and security set on the object.  The two tables are joined by an Id.  I would like to write a query that shows what changed between the current state and the previous version.

#### Table 1 Current State:

**Id, Metadata1, Metadata2, Security**
1, abc, xyz, private

#### Table 2 Previous Versions:

**Id, Metadata1, Metadata2, Security**
1, abc, def, public

I would like to run a query that would display that tells me that data in the metadata2 column plus security have changed between the current state and previous state

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Select table2.Id, table2.Metadata1,table2.metadata2,table2.security from table1 INNER JOINT table2 ON
Table1.Metadata1!=table2.metadata OR Table1.Metadata2!=Table2.Metadata2 OR Table1.Security!=Table2.Security;

Comment: Its MSSQL sentax